# Import current module from an imported module in python Django (importing loops)

Tags: python, django

Take the following pseudo-code for example

`models.py`

```
from django.db import models
from django.core.exceptions import ValidationError
from .methods import list_eligible_badges


class User(models.Model):
    handle = models.SlugField(max_length=200)

class Permission(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    badge = models.SlugField(max_length=200)
    def clean(self):
        super(Permission, self).clean()
        allowed_badges = list_eligible_badges()
        try:
            allowed_badges.index(self.badge)
        except:
            raise ValidationError('This user is not eligible for this privilege')
```

`methods.py`

```
from .models import User

def list_eligible_badges(user_handle):
    user_in_context = User.objects.get(handle=user_handle)
    # do some validation on the user_in_context to figure out what 
    # badge is this user eligible for then return a list of badges
    # allowed for this user
```

The above code defines two related data models, `User` and `Permission` where each permission is associated with a user. and in the file `methods.py` we have a method, `list_eligible_badges` where this method takes the user_handle (unique slug identifier of a user) and returns a list of slugs for the permissions that this particular user is eligible for.

And then the `list_eligible_badges` method is being used in the clean function of the `Permission` model to validate each permission before it's added to the database.

Everything seems fine, except that when running the code, it shows the error:

> File "methods.py", line 1, in
>
> > from .models import User

> ImportError: cannot import name 'User' from '.models'

Even though it doesn't show this error when importing `methods.py` from any other module other than `models.py`

it looks like this creates some sort of importing loop! As both files, `models.py` and `methods.py` import from each other. and unfortunately, I have to define the method `list_eligible_badges` externally as it will be reused by multiple other modules and I can not define it without importing the `User` data model.

So how can I handle this? is there anything like PHP's require_once in python?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One thing you could do is importing locally:

```py
class Permission(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    badge = models.SlugField(max_length=200)

    def clean(self):
        from .methods import list_eligible_badges
        super(Permission, self).clean()
        allowed_badges = list_eligible_badges()
```

Comment: Well, That seems to work but I'm not sure how! doesn't this still make a loop?

Comment: @Menas What happened previously was: Python loads the models.py file. This file requires the methods.py file. This file requires the models.py file. This file requires the... and so on. Thats the circular import error you had. With the local import, python imports models.py, but there is no "direct" statement to also load methods.py. Only once clean() is executed, the need for methods.py arises, and it can then safely be imported

Comment: I see! That makes sense. Thank you so much for this nice solution and for the explanation

Comment: @Menas No problem :) Please mark the answer as accepted, if it solved your problem